# Finding the analytic function given the imaginary part

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I have to find the analytic function of the variable $z= x + iy$ whose imaginary part is
$$
v=\ln (x^2 + y^2).
$$

Do I solve this using Cauchy?
Or is there another method?

Comment: Yes, you generally solve such a problem with the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Potato you have such a sweet name ^_^ You have to watch this : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJdO5gpe2dg

Comment: I think that proud means that you've done something good and it makes you feel good about yourself in a kind of weird way." -Baby Potato
Omg this is so cute <3

Answer (score 2):

"you generally solve such a problem with the Cauchy-Riemann equations" -@Potato

If $f=u+iv$ is an analytic function then it satisfies $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$

$$u_x=v_y$$ $$\implies u_x=\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2}$$ $$\implies u=2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)+g(y)$$ $$\implies u_y=-\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}+g'(y)$$ $$\implies -v_y=-\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}+g'(y)$$ $$\implies -\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}=-\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}+g'(y)$$ $$\implies g'(y)=0\implies g(y)=c$$

Thus, $u=2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)+c$

and hence function $f=\left(2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)+c\right)+i(\ln(x^2+y^2))$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if $z=x+iy$, then $v(z)=\ln(|z|^2)$.

If $z=re^{i\theta}$ then $\ln(z)=\ln(re^{i\theta})=\ln(r)+i\theta$ in some branch. 
Then $\ln(z^2)\ln(r^2e^{2i\theta})=\ln(r^2)+2i\theta$.

Notice that here $\ln(r^2)=\ln(|z|^2)$, and this is in the real part of $\ln(z^2)$, but you want it in the imaginary part. How to get out of $\ln(z^2)$ a function that has its real part in the imaginary part?